# Expected value of signals

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am trying to learn DPS. A couple of explanations are based on statistics. I would like to understand what is and how coherence works, but I am stuck on its definition.

I found the following definition of coherence:
$$C(\omega)=\frac{S_{XY}(\omega)}{\sqrt{S_{XX}(\omega)S_{YY}(\omega)}}$$
while a definition of $S_{XY}(\omega)$ is related to cross spectrum by DFT by the formula:
$$r_{xy}[k]=E\{x[n]y[n-k]\}$$
How to understand expected value here? Unfortunately the explanation I found, e.g. on Wikipedia, is based on probability:
$$E[X]=\sum_{i=1}^{\inf}p_ix_i$$
I understand its simple examples such as flipping a coin or throwing or rolling dice etc. When I look at this definition: $E\{x[n]y[n-k]\}$, I don't know where the probability term is.

Comment: Can you fill in some details here: relate $r_{xy}$ to $S$ and provide the definitions of $x[n]$ and $y[n]$

Comment: Apparently $X$ and $Y$ are random variables, so the expectation is with respect to their joint distribution.

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are simply time domain signals in signal processing. $r_{xy}$ and $S_{XY}$ are related by Fourier Transform (DFT particularly).